# Mathematics in Computer Graphics

Tags: 3d, mathematics, vector-graphics, vectors, linear-algebra

Can you please recommend some topic for research work related to mathematics in CG?
(Maybe something like "Affine transformations in CG")

Comment: The rendering equation.

Comment: This isnt such a bad question but needs some more focus. Just saying mathematics in computer graphics catches mostly all of the math i was taught in university, and school. CG is mathematical modeling after all.

Comment: Not sure if this fits here, but Straight Skeletons are a thing I'd like to research on.